# How to get file properties and upload a file from ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6, ionic4

I am trying to upload a file from mobile to google bucket using ionic 4. Although a file can upload into the could. I am struggling to get the file properties out of file object.

Here is my method,

```
async selectAFile() {

    const uploadFileDetails = {
      name: '',
      contentLength: '',
      size: '',
      type: '',
      path: '',
    };

    this.fileChooser.open().then(uri => {

      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uri).then(newUrl => {
        let dirPath = newUrl.nativeURL;

        const dirPathSegments = dirPath.split('/');
        dirPathSegments.pop();
        dirPath = dirPathSegments.join('/');

        (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
          newUrl.nativeURL,
          function(fileEntry) {
            uploadFileDetails.path = newUrl.nativeURL;

            const file: any = getFileFromFileEntry(fileEntry);

            //log 01 
            console.log({ file });

            uploadFileDetails.size = file.size;
            uploadFileDetails.name = `${newUrl.name
              .split(':')
              .pop()}.${file.type.split('/').pop()}`;
            uploadFileDetails.type = file.type;

            async function getFileFromFileEntry(fileEntry) {

              try {
                return await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                  fileEntry.file(resolve, reject)
                );
              } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
            }

          },
          function(e) {
            console.error(e);
          }
        );
      });
    });

    // here uploadFileDetails is simller to what I declared at the top ;)
    // I wan't this to be populated with file properties
    // console.log(uploadFileDetails.name) --> //''

    const uploadUrl = await this.getUploadUrl(uploadFileDetails);

    const response: any = this.uploadFile(
      uploadFileDetails,
      uploadUrl
    );

    response
      .then(function(success) {
        console.log({ success });
        this.presentToast('File uploaded successfully.');
        this.loadFiles();
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log({ error });
      });
  }
```

even though I can `console.log` the file in log 01. I am unable to get file properties like, `size`, `name`, `type` out of the `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` function. basically, I am unable to populate `uploadFileDetails` object. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried file transfer plugin? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer

Comment: Yep. the file is uploading that is not an issue. I was not able to get value out of `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` function. basically I was unable to send file name or size to the back-end that was the problem. `uploadFile` is actually using file Transfer plugin. I changed my approach and was able to figure it out. thank you for your comment. I will post it my answer when I got time thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### you actually need **4** `Ionic` `Cordova` plugins to upload a file after getting all the metadata of a file.

1. [FileChooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser)

   > Opens the file picker on Android for the user to select a file, returns a file URI.
2. [FilePath](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path)

   > This plugin allows you to resolve the native filesystem path for Android content URIs and is based on code in the aFileChooser library.
3. [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)

   > This plugin implements a File API allowing read/write access to files residing on the device.
4. [File Trnafer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer)

   > This plugin allows you to upload and download files.

#### getting the file's metadata.

- `file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` with `fileEntry.file` give you all the metadata you need, except the **file name**. There is a property called `name` in the metadata but it always contains value *content*.
- To get the human readable file name you need `filePath`. But remember you can't use returning file path to retrieve metadata. For that, you need the original url from `fileChooser`.
- `filePathUrl.substring(filePathUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)` is used to get only file name from `filePath`.
- You need `nativeURL` of the file in order to upload it. Using file path returning from `filePath` is not going to work.

```
    getFileInfo(): Promise<any> {
            return this.fileChooser.open().then(fileURI => {
                return this.filePath.resolveNativePath(fileURI).then(filePathUrl => {
                    return this.file
                        .resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(fileURI)
                        .then((fileEntry: any) => {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                fileEntry.file(
                                    meta =>
                                        resolve({
                                            nativeURL: fileEntry.nativeURL,
                                            fileNameFromPath: filePathUrl.substring(filePathUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
                                            ...meta,
                                        }),
                                    error => reject(error)
                                );
                            });
                        });
                });
            });
        }
```

#### select a file from the file system of the mobile.

```
async selectAFile() {

    this.getFileInfo()
        .then(async fileMeta => {

            //get the upload 
            const uploadUrl = await this.getUploadUrl(fileMeta);

            const response: Promise < any > = this.uploadFile(
                fileMeta,
                uploadUrl
            );

            response
                .then(function(success) {
                    //upload success message                       
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    //upload error message
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //something wrong with getting file infomation
        });
}
```

#### uploading selected file.

This depends on your backend implementation. This is how to use **File Transfer** to upload a file.

```
uploadFile(fileMeta, uploadUrl) {

    const options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'file',
      fileName: fileMeta.fileNameFromPath,
      headers: {
        'Content-Length': fileMeta.size,
        'Content-Type': fileMeta.type,
      },
      httpMethod: 'PUT',
      mimeType: fileMeta.type,
    };

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    return fileTransfer.upload(file.path, uploadUrl, options);
  }
```

hope it helps. :)

Comment: It helps me a lot. Could you be so kind to share your "getUploadUrl" function thank you